# WpBakery Page builder Tour module (accordion)

Tags: wordpress

I have `WpBakery Page builder` bundled with my `WordPress` theme. For one of my page, I have used Tour module. From the module setting, i collapsed all tabs at initial start. But my problem is- after opening a tab, I am unable to collapse any tabs. In mobile view, I found this bothersome. Because people need to go through all content of each tab to another tab.

So, I asked someone to code it for me:

```
for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName('vc_tta-title-text').length; i++) {
        document.getElementsByClassName('vc_tta-title-text')[i].addEventListener('click',function(event){

           if(event.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector('div.vc_tta-panel-body').style.display === 'block'){

               setTimeout(function(){
                   event.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector('div.vc_tta-panel-body').style.display = 'none';
               },1000)

           }else{
               setTimeout(function(){
                   event.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector('div.vc_tta-panel-body').style.display = 'block';
               },1000)
           }
        }, false);
    }
```

But this code only works from google developer console, not when I put it in my snippets plugin.